# ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR from a scaled nodejs application gear to scaled mysql application gear

Tags: php, mysql, node.js, sails.js, openshift

I've searched and found many posts about setting up one database for use across two scaled applications but none of the suggestions on the post have solved my problem.

Using a free OpenShift account I have set up two applications.

The first is a php/mysql application where mysql is on it's own gear (not embedded).  I can connect to the mysql application from my php code on the scaled gear and get a simple database query results back.  Everything works as expected.

My second application is a nodejs (sails) application.  It appears that I can connect to the gear that has mysql but I"m getting an error.

> Details:  Error: Could not connect to MySQL: Error:
>   ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: Access denied for user
>   'adminxQbueDZ'@'172.16.4.243' (using password: YES)

I am able to telnet from my nodejs gear to the mysql gear and get a positive response back.

I have adjusted mysql database permission for the user, added other users and still am not able to connect.  I can connect form my php gear fine with both credentials.

Has anyone had this issue? Have any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: Do you have access to your `my.conf` for mysql? And also, what are the grants for this user? is it `'USER' @ '%'` or `'USER' @ 'localhost'`?

Comment: it's 'USER' @ % in the mysql.user table.   The GRANTS are -  GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'adminxQbueDZ'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD...   I have access to /mysql/conf/my.cnf (i don't see my.conf).

Comment: Can you just try this - look in your `my.cnf` file for the following line: `bind-address="127.0.0.1" ` (*the value might be something else*), could you comment that out and make it look like this: `#bind-address="127.0.0.1" `. Then restart it and give it a shot

Comment: sigh.  I can't comment it out and have it applied because a restart replaces edits with a default configuration and open shift environment variables but based on what I've read I think you found the issue.   Looking for a way around that...

Comment: If my memory serves me correctly, there is a way in mysql to set allowed hosts, just check for that!